# Understanding retry value in Apache Load Balancer Configuration

Tags: apache-httpd, tomcat, load-balancing

We are using `mod_proxy` to balance load between our backend servers . We have different setup and some of the backend servers either runs on `tomcat\jboss`. The `balancer configuation` is as follows

`BalancerMember http://server1:21080 min=1 max=1000 loadfactor=1  retry=1 timeout=240 route=tc_server1
 BalancerMember http://server2:21080 min=1 max=1000 loadfactor=1  retry=1 timeout=240 route=tc_server2
 BalancerMember http://server3:21080 min=1 max=1000 loadfactor=1  retry=1 timeout=240 route=tc_server3`

The issue for us is that once a backend server is in error state, further requests are still getting forwarded to that server. Is it because `retry` was set to only 1 sec in our configuration? What does actually `retry` specify. Does that mean that once a host is in error state, do not send further requests to that server till the number of seconds was set to `retry` value. If that is the case setting the `retry` value to a higher number can be a better option for us. We can set it to a value which will be enough to resolve the bad node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , set the retry value to some **higher** number.

**retry:**

Connection pool worker retry timeout in seconds. If the connection pool worker to the backend server is in the error state, Apache will not forward any requests to that server until the timeout expires. This enables to shut down the backend server for maintenance and bring it back online later. A value of 0 means always retry workers in an error state with no timeout.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: The timeout you are talking here is it the value of retry parameter or you are talking of timeout parameter which was already set to a higher number in our case .

Comment: i am talking about the `retry` parameter , as you asked in the question. There is a timeout for retry , the higher the value , the later it will retry it. hopefully it is clear